# Graphql: Could not find generator 'graphql:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I created a new Ruby on Rails application and I just installed `graphql` gem, since I want to use *Graphql* for the project. But each time I run

```
rails generate graphql:install
```

I get the error below

> Could not find generator 'graphql:install'. Maybe you meant 'channel', 'assets' or 'generator'
>   Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

I have done research and also implemented a few solutions but none seems to be working. I need some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's what worked for me:**

Make sure that you have the latest version of `graphql`.

For my case, I was running `graphql 0.9.2` which was out of date

I had to open the **Gemfile** of my project and added the latest version of `graphql` to the **Gemfile**

```
gem 'graphql', '~> 1.9.12'
```

And then ran the command below to install/update `graphql`

```
bundle install
```

Afterwhich I tried running `graphql:install` again and it worked

```
rails generate graphql:install
```

If this does not work, check to see if you have `graphql-relay` gem in your Gemfile and remove it.

And then run `bundle install`

That's all.

**I hope this helps**